# Make "move conversation to chat" easier from the very beginning of the discussion

Tags: feature-request

When a discussion starts in the comments, it's not easy to open a chat room and copy all the comments to it. It's easier to wait for that message about "moving the conversation to chat", that does this automatically.

But we are always being reminded that "comments is not a space for lengthy discussions", but nobody seems to have the patience (or time) to opening chat rooms, copying/pasting the messages (with respective authors), and finally putting a link in the original thread, not to mention erase the comments later.

So, I suggest that a link to move the discussion to chat should be available (maybe as an icon) since the second comment (or something like that).

What do you think?

Comment: This topic has come up before because, yes, it would definitely make a lot of things easier, but I think I remember someone saying it isn't that simple to implement because there is a reputation minimum that is required to actually make chat rooms so new users wouldn't be able to move to chat, or something similar to that. Most times I've seen it brought up that was the conversation, "yes we've looked into it but its not trivial to implement because of new user issues"

Comment: @Not_Here The new user would not have this button. As I programmer, I tell you this is nothing difficult: `if ($userRep > 10) echo "<a href='$ref'><img src='$src'></a>";`. C'mon, this site is worth almost one billion dollars, I'm sure you can come up with a solution. Besides, the "new user problem" would be a problem the way it is now, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm just telling you what I've heard said on this topic

Comment: How important is it that the first few comments are in the chat room? I would just post a link to the post; "Hi guys, here we discuss *this post*. Follow the link for context."

Comment: In any case, the community team is not really active here so you might be better off asking this on [meta.se].

Comment: @Keelan change *first few comments* with as many comments you like. Usually the number of comments after which you moderators came and move it to chat in a way that we, normal users, can't do.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how that is a reply to what I wrote. I wrote that I think it's not that important to copy the first comments of the discussion, as you can just post a link to the post in the chat room. How many comments are not there isn't really important for that.

Comment: @Keelan Yes I can create two links (one to the chat room, and one back to the original post), but this keeps the whole conversation divided in two places. I think that a link to move the whole conversation to a chat room would be a much more easy, elegant and clean solution.

Comment: Seems like this suggestion is covered in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106467/205264 and its related posts. I can agree that it could be useful, though I see a problem UX-wise (don't want too many buttons). I couldn't find but can remember what Not_Here mentions, that the 20 rep threshold causes issues. In any case, as mentioned before, I don't think it's a big problem to have the conversation in two places, as usually no new people join the chat room without having read the post.

Comment: "OK, the 'yet' was 4 years ago – and 'the future' is now. Still impossible? Whom to beg, where to nag for it?" I will keep with my long discussions on comments, until the message to "move to chat" appears. Simple. It's an easy to solve problem (specially for a super-rich company like SE), I don't get this habit of using workarounds when a clean solution is totally viable. Right now I see one button and two links on the right of this panel (Save Edits, cancel and help). One button and three links would hurt anyone?